# What's the opposite word of "aforementioned"

Tags: word-request

I am writing a paper and want to use a word which has the opposite meaning of "aforementioned", i.e. something will be mentioned in following parts.

Comment: You can rephrase it to "mentioned above" and use "mentioned below" as its opposite.

Comment: From M-W.com: [below; ensuing, following, subsequent, succeeding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aforementioned). There are many similar results in [a search for “aforementioned antonym”](https://www.google.com/search?q=aforementioned+antonym). Please add details about your preliminary research and remaining confusion or this question may be closed as “answerable by dictionary”.

Comment: I think you were looking for the word: "hereinafter"

Comment: I'd say the word "following" would be the best antonym in this case.

Answer (score 4):

### What is the reason?

Are you trying to introduce the reader to an argument or trying to hold the reader's interest?

Academic papers often need to **let the reader know what is going to be said**. Otherwise the reader will likely stop reading since the paper will seem irrelevant to them. Sentences that list some topics then end with a "... will be discussed." are fairly common.

Possibly you trying to **introduce an argument** into the paper. In this case it would be more natural to simply state what you want, without any details about how more will be discussed. The reader will expect justification in the following paragraphs.

### Straight answer

These words can be used as part of an opposite meaning: below; ensuing, following, subsequent, succeeding

> "The presidential agenda will be discussed below"
>
> "The following evidence will convince the jury beyond a reasonable doubt that my defendant is innocent of all charges."
>
> "The proposed hypothesis will be substantiated by the subsequent details."
>
> "Despite the compelling nature of this argument, the succeeding details provide an alternative explanation."